# PHP switch entering case 0: even if there is a valid case?

Tags: php

The following switch case statement was supposed to execute the value of case "january": but instead it is executing the value of case 0: ,can anybody tell me why it is doing this?
CODE:

```
<?php
$a = "january";
switch ($a)
{
    case 0:
    case 3:
        echo "The value is either 0 or 3";
        break;
        echo "0/2";
        break;
    case "january":
        echo "january";
        break;
    case "march":
        echo "The value is ";
        break;
    case 2:
        echo "The value is 2";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Here is ur default message";
        break;
}
?>
```

By the way it is doing the same for the case "march"....?

Comment: what is var_dump($a)?

Comment: what makes you think `switch` works with strings?

Comment: What's your question? All of this is expected behavior. If you expected something else to happen, you need to explain what and why.

Comment: You have to move the string cases up, then the numbers, then the default; but knowing that php coerces values, this may not work satisfactory either.

Comment: @Alnitak Are you saying that `switch` doesn't work with strings?

Comment: @Jack mostly I'm saying it won't work if you mix strings and numbers.

Comment: @Alnitak That makes more sense :)

Answer (score 8):

```
$a = 'january';

var_dump($a == 0);
var_dump($a === 0);
var_dump($a == '0');
var_dump($a === '0');
```

Output:

```
bool(true)
bool(false)
bool(false)
bool(false)
```

Read up on [Type Juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). [Apparently](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) `switch` uses [loose comparison](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose):

> **Note:**
>   Note that switch/case does [loose comparision](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php#types.comparisions-loose).

Comment: So what is the solution for that ?

Comment: What's the problem that requires a solution?

Comment: @pra - checkout the suggested duplicate link.

Comment: Make sure $a and the cases always have the same type, e.g.: string

Comment: @David I thought the output would be "january" but not "The value is 0 or 3".Can u tell me how to fix it so that it will echoes "january".

Comment: @hajiman: Why not just write your own `if`/`else` tree that tests exactly what you want instead of using `switch`/`case`? The `switch`/`case` control structure is great if it happens to do exactly what you want, but it not, don't try to cram a square peg in a round hole.

Comment: thanks all, i now understand what was the causing the problem...

Answer (score 1):

PHP has some problems that can cause this kind of behaviour, in this case the problem comes from the fact that you are using different types on your Switch.

Try this code:

```
echo (0 == "january") ? "true\n" : "false\n"; // Echoes true
```

One way to work around this is to use only strings on your switch, like so:

```
switch ($a)
{
    case "0":
    case "3":
        echo "The value is either 0 or 3";
        break;
        echo "0/2";
        break;
    case "january":
        echo "january";
        break;
    case "march":
        echo "The value is ";
        break;
    case "2":
        echo "The value is 2";
        break;
    default:
        echo "Here is ur default message";
        break;
}
```

This will work fine, because 0 == "0" but "january" != "0"

Switch uses simple == to compare the values of the variable with the ones on each case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the numbers. You can't mix numbers and strings when using a switch statement.